# How does the A get cancelled out in $\int \sigma x dA$

Tags: calculus

The following equation is the sum of moments around the $x$ axis for a **uniformly distributed load** on a prismatic bar.

$M_x = \int \sigma x dA = Fx'$

Where:

$M = Fx = Force * Perpendicular Distance = Moment$

$\sigma = F/A = Stress$

$x$ is the $x$ coordinate of $dA$

$F$ is the resultant force acting along the centriod.

$A$ is the cross-sectional area.

$x'$ is the $x$ coordinate of the centriod.

---

I am confused where the $A$ cancels out in equation. For example how is $M_x$ =$\int \sigma xdA$ meant to be the sum of all the moments when $(F/A)xdA$ is not even a moment ($M$) ?

The only way I can make sense of it is to do the following:

$M_x = \sigma \int xdA$

$M_x = (F/A)\int xdA$

Then $\int xdA$ is creating a term that has factors of $A$ and $B$

$M_x = (F/A)AB$

Then $A$  cancels in the $F/A$ term giving: $M_x = FB$

But this is assuming that $\int xdA$ creates a term with $A$ as a factor...

---

Summary question: How does the $A$ term cancel out to create a moment, $M$.

Comment: What do you mean A cancels out? I do not see A cancelling out in the first part of your question.

Comment: If $M_x = Fx'$ where $F$ is the resultant force and $x'$ is the position of the centriod then $Fx' = \int \sigma xdA$. This means that the $A$ in $\sigma$ needs to cancel somewhere.

Comment: What do you think the units of $dA$ are?

Comment: $A$ is a $distance^2$ unit... so $dA$ would be a $distance^2$ also?